# Making an img (used as a button) disabled

Tags: javascript, html

the image is:

```
<img id="lawnButton" src="images/mowing.png"  width="15%" height="45%" alt="mowLawn" border="0" onclick="cutLawn()">
```

The code in the .js is:

```
document.getElementById("lawnButton").disabled = true;
```

Is there anything off the bat that I am doing incorrectly? The image still works as a button after the code is executed.

Comment: I don't think images have a `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Do you know of anything like it that would work?

Comment: You could also surround img with <button>, and then you could set button disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image tag doesn't have that attribute. Try removing the event.

```
var lawn = document.getElementById("lawnButton");
lawn.onclick = function() {
    //do code
    lawn.onclick = null;
}

//.. code to re-enable the trigger
if (some condition) lawn.onclick = cutLawn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since images don't have a disabled attribute, you might want to set some flag to it to be used in `cutLawn`.

You could use a class. For example, to disabled the button:

```
button = document.getElementById("lawnButton")
button.className = button.className+ " disabled"
```

And then in `cutLawn`:

```
cutLawn = function(){
    button = document.getElementById("lawnButton")
    if button.className.match(/disabled/){
     return false;
    }
    // ...
}
```